# Referencing cached results within a model while confirming to SOLID principles?

Tags: php, solid-principles

I have a **Offers** class which extends my base Model class and I want to return all the special offers, but each offer contains relations to other models' results. How can I reference records that I cached in an organized manner?

Model.php

```
abstract class Model {
  protected $db;

  public function __construct() {
       $this->db = new \Db;
  }
  abstract public function getRecords($params);
};
```

Offers.php

```
class Offers extends Model {
    public function getRecords($params) {
       $this->db->query('
          SELECT title, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(properties_ids) AS properties, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(cities_ids) AS cities, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(countries_ids) AS countries
       ');

       $results = array();
       while ($temp = $this->db->fetchAssoc()) {
          $results[] = $this->formatResult($temp);
       }
       return $results;
    }

    public function setProperties($properties) {
         $this->properties = $properties;
    }

    public function setCities($cities) {
         $this->cities = $cities;
    }

    public function setCountries($countries) {
         $this->countries = $countries;
    }

    public function formatResult(&$record) {
         if ( $record['properties'] ) {
             // convert a csv string into an array
             \Helper::makeArray($record['properties']);

             $properties = array();
             foreach( $record['properties'] as $id ) {
                 if ( $this->properties[$id] ) {
                     $properties[] = $this->properties[$id];
                 }
             }
             $record['properties'] = $properties;
         }
    }
}
```

Currently I'm doing this:

```
$properties = (new Properties)->getRecords($filters);
$cities = (new Cities)->getRecords($filters);
$countries = (new Countries)->getRecords($filters);

$offers = new Offers;
$offers->setProperties($properties);
$offers->setCities($cities);
$offers->setCountries($countries);
$offerRecords = $offers->getRecords();

$events = new Events;
$events->setProperties($properties);
$eventRecords = $events->getRecords();
```

Is there a way I can do this without having to rely on constantly creating **set** methods? My models each reference the results of each other.

The way I was doing it prior to **set** methods was passing parameters to **getRecords** but since I created an abstract class and method, the parameter count must be the same and it wasn't consistent so I abandoned it that way.

Some theories/ideas:

1. Possible create the $properties variable within **Offers::getRecords** but I'm using the same results for other models, and I want to use that consistent result (on the same page).
2. Modify all models to self-cache, but this would involve extra logic requiring a cache override
3. Create a general setModelResults method in my abstract class so at least I can use one method instead of define one each time.

**Eg**

```
public function setModelResults($modelName, array $results) {
   $this->{$modelName} = $results;
}

$offers->setModelResults('Properties', $properties);
```

4. Implement caching at the model level and refactoring getRecords to directly call the referencing models, either by adding a static model function to make an instance (cleaner imo) or creating an instance.

**Eg**

```
class Properties {

    public function getRecords($params) {
       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
       if ( $params['id'] ) {
          $sql.= ' WHERE id = '. $id;
       }

       $results = Db::cache->get($sql, array(

       ));
       if (!$results) {
           Db::query($sql);
           Db::cache->set($sql, array(
               'expires' => (new DateTime)->add(new DateTimeInterval('PT1H'));
           );
       }
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) { 
        return parent::model($className);
    }

}
```

Usage in offers:

```
    class Offers {

    public function getRecords($params) {
       $this->db->query('
          SELECT title, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(properties_ids) AS properties, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(cities_ids) AS cities, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(countries_ids) AS countries
       ');

       $this->properties = Properties::model()->getRecords();
       // alternatively
       // $this->properties = new Properties;

       $results = array();
       while ($temp = $this->db->fetchAssoc()) {
          $results[] = $this->formatResult($temp);
       }
       return $results;
    }

        public function formatResult(&$record) {
             if ( $record['properties'] ) {
                 // convert a csv string into an array
                 \Helper::makeArray($record['properties']);


                 $properties = array();


                 // Method 1
                 foreach( $properties as $id ) {
                     if ( $this->properties[$id] ) {
                         $properties[] = $this->properties[$id];
                     }
                 }

                 // Method 2
                 /* alternatively */
                 $this->propertiesResults = $this->properties->getRecords();
                 foreach( $properties as $id ) {
                     if ( $this->propertiesResults[$id] ) {
                         $properties[] = $this->propertiesResults[$id];
                     }
                 }

                 $record['properties'] = $properties;
             }
        }

    }
```

Comment: "The way I was doing it prior to set methods was passing parameters to getRecords but since I created an abstract class and method" What was the motivating factor in moving away from this? How does the abstract classes getRecords get called?

Comment: I want to make the arguments for getRecords consistent. With the way I did it before, it was: `getRecords($filters, $properties, $cities);` for one model, and `getRecords($filters, $countries)` for another. They don't all use the same result sets since they have different relations.

Comment: Another idea I had was maybe just setup caching at the model level per unique query and do something inside the `formatResult` node like `Properties::getRecords()` (would have to make my models more static).

Comment: @mederomuraliev I'd definitely move away from ActiveRecord patterns. Focus on solving the problem in your model, then figure out how to persist and retrieve it as well as optimize these. What business problem are you solving here? What are those properties?

Comment: @plalx - You're right in that I'm basing it off AR patterns. The properties are many to many, an offer or event can belong to multiple properties/units.

Comment: @plalx What's the reason for moving away from AR patterns? Just curious

Comment: @mederomuraliev It lets you focus on the business problem rather than persistence concerns and artificial associations for the sake of easier object navigation. Look at your model, all that code and no one could even guess what's the actual purpose of the model and what business problem it aims to solve.